# How can I make text slowly slide to the left when making other text visible in a row?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Is there a way to make the "chapter" text slowly move to the left, like in an animation, when clicking the floatingActionButton in the code below?

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool visible = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: const Text('Flutter Demo Home Page'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Text(
              'Chapter ',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
            ),
            Visibility(
              visible: visible,
              maintainAnimation: true,
              maintainState: true,
              child: AnimatedOpacity(
                opacity: visible ? 1 : 0,
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                child: const Text(
                  '01',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(
            () => visible = !visible,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I would like the "chapter" text to move in the same duration applied in the AnimatedOpacity Widget.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own custom animation or use a package like:

> [animate_do](https://pub.dev/packages/animate_do)

After just wrap your widget with **SlideInLeft** and customize the duration of the animation, with the property **animate** you can specify when launch your animation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [animated_text_kit](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_text_kit) Package

```
SizedBox(
width: 250.0,
child: DefaultTextStyle(
style: const TextStyle(
  fontSize: 30.0,
  fontFamily: 'Bobbers',
),
child: AnimatedTextKit(
  animatedTexts: [
    TyperAnimatedText('It is not enough to do your best,'),
    TyperAnimatedText('you must know what to do,'),
    TyperAnimatedText('and then do your best'),
    TyperAnimatedText('- W.Edwards Deming'),
  ],
  onTap: () {
    print("Tap Event");
  },
 ),
),
);
```